# Align the html table cell data (having one table and button) in middle

Tags: html, css

[image: Screenshot of table row]

Here, in Second column i have one Table (created dynamically according to data) and one span having css properties as -

```
span.addPeriod {
width: 80px;
height: 15px;
float: right;
background-color: #A6A6A6;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px;
vertical-align: middle; }

span.addPeriod:hover { 
background-color: #507BAF; }

span.addPeriod a {
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #FFF;}
```

I am trying to align span "Add Period" in center of cell (vertical) as Test, Xyzz.
Please help.

Comment: span don't have vertical align by default. Use it for td and not for span. Or use some hack with display: table

Answer (score 0):

Try to set vertical alignment of second column cell as middle.

Answer (score 0):

With your current css, vertical-align does not affect anything because the span's height is only 15px.

You can do the following:

1. Set the span height to 100% (of row height). Vertical align will only be helpfull when its height is the same as the row height. Currently your height is set to 15px so the inner link will still show at the top of the cell.
2. Use absolute positioning to position the span within the cell

   position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-7px;

Hope this helps!